# How to re-order text labels for y-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, yaxis

I am SUPER new to R.

I am trying to re-order the tick marks on my y-axis on a graph I created. Is there anyone who can tell me how to re-arrange/pick the order in which they line up? They labels are just elements from the "wheel_spot" vector. What I'm trying to show is how many of the dots on my graph fall in each category, but my graph will make more sense if the labels flow in a particular order.

Here's the graph right now:

[image]

My code is:

```
graph <- ggplot(data=new_data, aes(x=bucket,y=wheel_spot, color=identifier)) + geom_jitter() + facet_grid(bucket~.)
graph
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You will need to reorder the factor levels of your variable in the order you want them to appear on the graph

Comment: Thanks Justin! That worked!!

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a new order in ylab:

```
graph <- ggplot(data=new_data, aes(x=bucket,y=wheel_spot, color=identifier)) + geom_jitter() + facet_grid(bucket~.) + ylab(labels=c(...))
```